# Spring: why do I need applicationContext.xml when I am using annotations?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am Spring newbie

Im trying to deploy my war file on tomcat using cargo and it complained about `applicationContext.xml` not being found in directory.

I further looked up where it should go and added a blank xml file `applicationContext.xml` to see if that works but then it complained something as

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
```

I am not sure why do I need `applicationContext.xml` and if I really need it, what should I put in there?

I am using `@annotations` as much as I could and my unit tests are also passing correctly, Meaning, I see that my beans do wire up correctly

Seniors, please help

Thank you

**UPDATE**

`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<xml>
</xml>
```

`src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml`

```
<beans></beans>
```

Comment: When you say cargo, do you mean http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container? Also could you show your Java Config and your web.xml?

Comment: how about web.xml (or are you using a Servlet 3 initializer)?

Comment: my bad, i have `web.xml` instead of `beans.xml`. I do not have any `beans.xml`

Comment: Ok, are you using `WebApplicationInitializer` or `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` by any chance? If so what is the content of the classes that implement/extend those?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51947/discussion-between-daydreamer-and-geoand)

Answer (score 4):

You have to "tell" your application where to look for files that describes your application context like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You may need to adjust the path under `<param-value>` but basically that's it.

I also recommend the minimun `applicationContext.xml` to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.here"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

In case you do not need Spring transaction management, feel free to remove the last line and related schema reference.

Also I'd like to mention that technically there **is** a way to get rid of `applicationContext.xml` **completely** but I really doubt it worth so. You may find [this article](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/01/spring-framework-without-xml-at-all.html) useful aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this part](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create) of the reference documentation, especially this phrase:

> The listener inspects the contextConfigLocation parameter. If the parameter does not exist, the
>   listener uses /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml as a default.

That would be where it is looking for an applicationContext.xml file and why.